# How do I install and use share plugin in PhoneGap 3

Tags: cordova

I couldn't find proper documentation or an answer in StackOverflow but couldn't find anything.

How do I enable a very simple share button that should send a link to platform share APIs?

Comment: What is "platform share APIs"?

Comment: `UIActivityViewController` in iOS for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call native device functionality, you'll have to use a plugin.

You can either look around online to see if somebody else has already created a plugin with the feature you want, or you could [create your own](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) by programming the native and javascript side. If you want to look around for the plugin, try the [plugin registry](http://plugins.cordova.io/). Adobe [also maintains a registry](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins), I have no idea if you can use those plugins without using Phonegap though. Finally, you can search around on github and the internet. There used to be a [phonegap plugin repository](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) - it has since been depreciated but hopefully the authors will have migrated their code to other github repos.